# Adding gauge chart to nvd3

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I have an angular frontend app that uses angular-nvd3. This is quite convenient for me.
Unfortunately I now need a gauge chart and because I create dynamic charts from a server response I don't want to build many conditions to include a different chart library.
There's not much information about gauge charts with d3.js or especially NVD3.
The only thing I found is this http://bl.ocks.org/tomerd/1499279 but that's only d3.js based code. If I don't want to mess up my angular app, I should integrate that in NVD3. Unfortunately I have no idea how this needs to be done.
Does anybody have a gauge chart working in NVD3 or alternative solutions?

Comment: What sort of gauge chart. nvd3 has a donut chart, can probably be adapted to be some sort of "gauge"

Comment: The link that I mentioned shows exactly what I'm looking for. A gauge with a needle and live data. Do you think the donut chart can be modified that intense to provide that?

Comment: Doubtful, probably too custom to tweak with nvd3 charts. As long as you are using nvd3, you have pure d3 available to you. Just use that example and make a custom chart.

Comment: did you succeed in your attempt? I do something wrong probably. I need somehow the same gauge visualization as you did :) @hans-höchtl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a simple gauge chart plugin for nvd3 a while ago, and while it's a bit hard-coded for our purposes you should to be able to modify it to your needs:

https://github.com/enplore/nvd3-charts

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I needed to get started.